# How to use cordova plugins in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic2, cordova-nativestorage

I'm new in ionic 2 and I use Typescript. I need use this pugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage or something like this. How can I import this plugin ? How to use plugin, which is not ionic native ?  It is possible ?

Comment: I've got a similar problem with the inAppPurchase plugin so I came across your post. Sadly you don't have  a solution for your problem. I am discussing my problem over here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-bundle-js-not-found/57541 maybe our problems are equal and can be solved the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily manage lot of Cordova plugins through [Ionic Native](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/) that is automatically installed with Ionic 2.

For example if you want Cordova Plugin Native Storage, you will find this plugin in Ionic Native docs, [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/native-storage/) and as you can see there is all steps that you should do to made plugin work.

In our case you have to install plugin via console:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage
```

Next import and use this plugin from Ionic Native in our app:

```
import {NativeStorage} from 'ionic-native';

NativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

Enjoy.

Comment: The question clearly states 'which is not ionic native'

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install the plugin using the following command:

```
ionic plugin cordova-plugin-nativestorage --save
```

Then, you can use the plugin as normal. Please check https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Few things to check:

- Make sure plugin has been installed. Please see the above command.
- Test on real devices
- Make sure your code is inside the `deviceready`
  event. `document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady,
  false);`

Comment: I'm using ionic 2 with typescript and I have problem to import them to my app. I mean somethink like this "import {plugin} from i_don't_know_from_what"

Comment: You dont need to import to your app. You can use `NativeStorage` directly, but it only works on the real device, if you test this on browser, it won't work.

Comment: Yes of course. I was testing on real device too but it's not working.

Comment: @bajky What exactly is the error. Is it working now? feel free to open an issue at our github page if it looks like a general issue : https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage/issues

Comment: @bajky also note that `browser` as a platform is supported, though its basically only a localstorage fallback.